# Shell script minification tools similar to jsMin et al?

Tags: bash, shell, minify

I'd like to compress some shell code for deployment on an embedded linux platform with limited flash memory

Obviously you could try to kludge things using regexes to search for whitespace, but the only safe way to do it is with a full parser.

Are there any minification tools (similar to jsMin, and the YUI Compressor) for shell scripting languages?

In particular I'm interested in the ash shell, but I'd accept something for bash :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have copious comments (which are relatively easily removed) and removed leading blanks on lines where it is not significant (and blank lines), then there is not much compression left to do.

I ran a crude test on 424 assorted shell scripts that I've written over the years, and there were 16561 input lines (386008 characters), and 11992 output lines (278349 characters).  The saving, therefore, was about 28%.

I used this almost trivial Perl script (which has not in any sense been optimized; it was originally going to write to a separate output file per input file - hence the explicit file handling instead of a simple `while (<>)` loop):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $file (@ARGV)
{
    open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Failed to open $file";
    my $line = <>;
    print $line;
    while ($line = <>)
    {
        next if $line =~ m/^#/;
        next if $line =~ m/^\s*$/;
        $line =~ s/^\s+//;
        $line =~ s/\s+$//;
        print $line;
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

This leaves the first line (typically the shebang line, though many of my scripts are old enough - and untended for long enough - that they use `:` instead of a shebang) unchanged.  This doesn't attempt to strip trailing comments (white space, hash, other characters) but I don't tend to use many of them.  Adding the substitute command:

```
        $line =~ s/\s+#[^\\'"`]*$//;
```

left me with 275035 characters from my corpus (and a saving of about 29%).  Replacing all the first lines with '`#!/bin/sh`' saves a little more.  There are multiple consecutive blanks or tabs in about 700 of the lines, but the extra space saving compressing them is rather limited (and many of them are searching for 'blank or tab' combinations, which should not be compressed).

Clearly, if a saving of about 1/3 the space is sufficient, then this script may be of some use, simplistic though it is.  Reducing the space much more would be hard, though, without running a serious risk of damaging the scripts you are minimizing.

Comment: Thanks! It's always great to have some stats :)

Comment: The device only has 8MB of flash memory and runs OpenWRT. I'm leaning towards building a custom stripped down image before resorting this I think.

Comment: A thought for you: could you devise a scheme where the scripts are stored in compressed files, and the shell (or a wrapper for the shell) decompresses the script into a temp file before running it?  However, you would have to look at fragmentation of disk space; shell scripts tend to be small individually.